# React: production styles are different from local

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm not sure how to describe this issue well but I am noticing different styles with my production build. My classes are all on production but they are having different results. For example a div with these styles:

```
{
 padding: 0 5px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px black solid
}
```

is resulting it different things. Locally this is resulting in a div with a width of 200px (including border and padding). But on production the div's total width is 212px.

Also my images have these styles locally but not on production:

[image]

which are coming from this last style element:

[image]

And i'm not sure what that is exactly but seems to be those are the styles  missing from production.

Comment: if you check your element style, isset your style override from another style in new build? 
in another word, can you set a specific class for needed element and try to represent style on production mode?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.